# Setting environment variables with `export` from within a script (for zsh) not working

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, environment

I use a script to set a number of environmental variables for developing with various Docker containers (setting ports for linked containers etc.), e.g. (for a PostgreSQL container):

```
export PERSIST_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT=`docker inspect --format='{{ (index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "5432/tcp") 0).HostPort  }}' deploy_persist_1`
```

This worked fine when I was using bash as my shell, but now I'm using zsh. My .zshrc has various `export`s which work fine, but none of the variables in this script make it into my environment and I don't understand why.

Comment: How are you running the script? `. script.sh`? `./script.sh`?

Comment: I had `chmod +x`'d it so was just running ./script.sh

Comment: `. script.sh` worked. Come to think of it I think that's what I did with bash. Looks like it's going to be one of those days...

Comment: Remember that sourcing a file with `. script.sh` is different from running a file like `./script.sh`.  The former runs the commands *in your current shell*, while the latter runs them *in a new process*.

Comment: But even if `./scipt.sh` is invoked in a new process, shouldn't the `export` export the variable in global context `environment`, i.e. make it visible in every new shell?